# Python import folder

Tags: python, import

I'm using Python 2.6.  I'm new at Python programming, so forgive my ignorance.  I have multiple directories with multiple packages.  My directory structure looks like this:

```
/disconfig
    __init__.py
    /LLE
        __init__.py
        /DIS
             __init__.py
        /Data
             __init__.py
/common
    __init__.py
    /LLE
       __init__.py
```

I need to be able to import both of the LLE directories to make the program work.  I can't add disconfig or common to PYTHONPATH because they both have an LLE directory.  When I do import LLE, it only pulls in one of them.  I've tried doing:

```
import disconfig.LLE
```

it errors saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./disconfig.py", line 9, in <module>
    import disconfig.LLE
  File "./disconfig.py", line 9, in <module>
    import disconfig.LLE
ImportError: No module named LLE
```

I've tried:

```
import disconfig
```

This works, but when I try to run code from within one of the modules:

```
LLE.DIS.runDisFunc
```

and it comes back saying

```
name 'LLE' not defined
```

If I try:

```
disconfig.LLE.DIS.runDisFunc
```

it says errors with:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'LLE'
```

I've been working on this for so long and can't wrap my brain around it.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Maybe there is one more thing to mention.  The files that are in these directories are generated by slice2py from ZeroC.  They place all of the generated .py files in the top-level directory (so under /disconfig).  The LLE directory has the **init**.py that has the imports of all of the generated .py files as well as "import DIS" and "import Data".  Then in DIS and Data, there are **init**.py files that include the imports specific to those modules.  So, more completely it looks like:

```
/disconfig
    __init__.py
    Attribute_ice.py
    DIS_ice.py
    DISControl_ice.py
    /LLE
        __init__.py
        /DIS
            __init__.py
        /Data
            __init__.py
```

If I change the module from disconfig to MDIS (as suggested) and do

```
import MDIS
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./disconfig", line 9, in <module>
    import MDIS
  File "/oudvmt/python/MDIS/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import LLE
  File "/oudvmt/python/MDIS/LLE/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Attribute_ice
ImportError: No module named Attribute_ice
```

If I try

```
import MDIS.LLE
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./disconfig", line 9, in <module>
    import MDIS.LLE
  File "/oudvmt/python/MDIS/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import LLE
  File "/oudvmt/python/MDIS/LLE/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Attribute_ice
ImportError: No module named Attribute_ice
```

I've tried moving the generated .py files into the subdirectories, but that caused other problems because the files in /DIS depend on the files in /Data (DIS_ice.py imports Attribute_ice.py, which is part of LLE/Data).  If I separate them, I get ImportErrors.

**More EDIT:**
I added all of the .py files to my **init**.py in the /MDIS directory and removed them from the **init**.py in the subdirectories.  Now I have nore more import errors using just "import MDIS".  However, now when I try my function

```
 disadmin = MDIS.LLE.DIS.DISAdminPrx.checkedCast()
```

I get

```
'module' object has no attribute 'DISAdminPrx'
```

In DISAdmin_ice.py, there is a class called DISAdminPrx and it does have a method of checkedCast.  I tried

```
disadmin = DISAdmin_ice.DISAdminPrx.checkedCast()
```

and

```
disadmin = MDIS.LLE.DIS.DISAdmin_ice.DISAdminPrx.checkedCast()
```

and any other combination I could think of.

**EDIT AGAIN**
Looks like it's a problem with the python converter I'm using from ZeroC.  They are helping me resolve it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: After running `import disconfig`, what is the output of `dir(disconfig)`?

Comment: ['Ice', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'cgi', 'cgitb', 'disconfig', 'escape', 'os', 'sys', 'traceback']

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your script is named `disconfig.py` so when you `import disconfig`  you call the script. You should named your script differently from your module.

**EDIT**

before

```
disadmin = MDIS.LLE.DIS.DISAdmin_ice.DISAdminPrx.checkedCast()
```

you should do

```
import MDIS.LLE.DIS.DISAdmin_ice
```

or do

```
from MDIS.LLE.DIS.DISAdmin_ice import DISAdminPrx
DISAdminPrx.checkedCast()
```

I really think that what I propose work but I can't explain why if someone could explain why in comprehensive words I'm sure the OP would be glad. It is explained in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages but I'm not sure that is in simple words.

Comment: Ok, I changed the module to MDIS and it still didn't work.  dir(MDIS) comes out as: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

Answer (score 1):

You need an `import LLE` statement in `disconfig/__init__.py`, then `import disconfig.LLE` should work.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import disconfig.LLE.DIS
disconfig.LLE.DIS.runDisFunc()
```

This is because Python does not automatically imports subpackages.

Answer (score 0):

write your own import file then import that
this was made to import my scripts.
repeat for every folder

```
#scripts
os.system("dir /b  Scripts\\*.py > dirb.txt")
file1=open("dirb.txt","r")
file2=open("temp.py","w")
for lines in file1.readlines():
    lines=lines.strip()
    string="import Scripts."+str(lines[0:-3])
    file2.write(string+"\n")
file1.close()
file2.close()
from temp import *
os.system("rem temp.txt")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).